# Convert from QBasic "Binary - Fast load and save" Format?

Tags: qbasic

I have several hundred games I wrote as a kid some 20 years ago saved in the QBasic 7's `.bas` "binary" output format (Not to be confused with executable "binaries")

I have been slowly converting these by hand with QBasic in DosBox to ASCII for posterity.

I am curious if anyone know anything about the encoding used by the format such that one could write a script to decode these en masse.

I have been poking at the data a bit, I believe it is beyond me.

For instance the HEX of "ABCD" saved in this format is

```
fc02 0100 0d00 a801 a801 0700 0102 0304
0605 0810 10ff ff24 00ff ff64 0100 0056
0000 005b 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0061
0052 0000 0000 0161 0000 0002 6162 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
000c 0000 0038 0000 005b 0009 0008 00ff
ffff ffff ffff ff01 0000 0000 0003 01
```

[image: QBasic Binary Save As Dialog]

Comment: You could probably automate it using something like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) if you're on Windows. Open DosBox and obtain its window info using Window Spy. Once you've done that, you can send keys to it using [`ControlSend`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) (see [`Send`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) for details on the syntax of keys). You might need delays between file dialog opening, saving, and program exit, so I'd use one or even multiple test files before executing things on your real files (I'd make a copy of the files first actually)

Comment: @eoredson The problem is that just running qbx.exe in a .bat file will just allow you to open files. As far as I'm aware, there is no switch for qbx.exe, or even another program, that allows you to batch convert files from the binary format to ASCII (I'd be more than happy to be wrong though!) Something like AutoHotkey to send key presses (or mouse clicks) to the DosBox window is probably the best option. Combined with its interface to Windows API functions like FindFirstFile, one can loop through several files, simulating the key presses for saving the file as ASCII and quitting for each file

Comment: @eoredson AFAIK, qbx will read key presses directly from the keyboard; meaning file redirection won't work. Aside from that, instructing the menus would still require interactive input, so you may as well work the file paths into the script that automates the interactive input.

Comment: @eoredson MS-DOS 4.0 added multitasking and a [`KEYBD$` special file name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#DOS,_TOS,_OS/2,_and_Windows), and DosBox may emulate those features, though you wouldn't be able to use `KEYBD$` to simulate input to qbx due to how its multitasking worked: [_This ... allowed specially-written programs to continue executing in a "background mode", where they had **no access to user input and output** until returned to the foreground._](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_4.0_(multitasking)#Features)

Comment: The predecessor of QBASIC and QuickBASIC, GW-BASIC, was command-based, which would have allowed this functionality: `LOAD"foo.bas" : SAVE"foo.bas",A : SYSTEM` would have done exactly what you wanted, assuming your program was a GW-BASIC program. You could repeat the `LOAD` and `SAVE` pair as many times as needed to convert your file (e.g. `foo.bas`) from GW-BASIC's particular binary format to ASCII (`,A`). QB was an IDE unable receive such commands. Commands like `LOAD` and `SAVE` became IDE menu items, so there was no way (no need?) to feed commands to QB.